# Using 2x remote method of Jquery Validate plugin for a single field

Tags: validation, jquery, jquery-validate

I've a form that is being validated with [Jquery's Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and I need a way to have, at least, 2 validations via Ajax on one same field...

Example: I've a field named Login, that accepts a Username or a Email and I need to verify if it is an existing Email in the Database or it is an existing Username in the Database, returning different messages and executing 2 different URL's to do these validations.

Is there anyway of calling 2 distinct remote methods with different messages and URL's or should I add 2 new method's based in AJAX synchronous calls?

**EDIT**

Ok, maybe I should say the reason why I want to call 2 different remote methods or create 2 AJAX synchronous calls:

The problem is that I'm using Zend and I'm doing a system that could validate errors on Server Side (via PHP) and on Client Side (via Jquery Validate, created on the fly by PHP classes that extends from the original Validators of Zend).

**Example**

```
class Esytek_Form_JqueryValidator_NotEmpty extends Zend_Validate_NotEmpty implements Esytek_Form_JqueryValidator_Interface {

    public function elementSetOptions(Zend_Form_Element $element){
        $element->setRequired(true);
    }

    public function getJqueryCode(){
        return 'required: true,';
    }

    public function getJqueryMessage($mensagem){
        foreach ($this->_messageVariables as $ident => $property) {
            $mensagem = str_replace("%$ident%", (string) $this->$property, $mensagem);
        }
        return 'required: "<br>'.$mensagem.'",';
    }

    public function getNewJqueryFunction(){
        return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

Esytek_Form_JqueryValidator_Interface

```
interface Esytek_Form_JqueryValidator_Interface extends Zend_Validate_Interface{

    public function elementSetOptions(Zend_Form_Element $element);

    public function getJqueryCode();

    public function getJqueryMessage($mensagem);

    public function getNewJqueryFunction();
}
```

There's another class that's to big to put there but, in short, all it does is call the methods of each Jquery Validator, aggregate all Jquery code inside a string and then, in the form, we should call a single method that writes up the jquery code that runs the validations.

In this context, I want to do a class that could generate more than one type of ajax validation in one field to support all possible cases that could happen on Ajax Validation for an input field... In other words, I need something like that:

```
    public function getNewJqueryFunction(){
        return array ('AjaxValidation_'.$count=>'$.validator.addMethod("tel_format"+'.$count.',
            function(value,element) {
                //Ajax call of URL
            }," ");'
        );
    }
```

Or something like **Esytek_Form_JqueryValidator_NotEmpty** that could implement more than one **remote** method in one field, so I can use that JqueryValidator in any Ajax call case.

In that way, my question is "what's the best approach and how can I do it in jquery's code?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if 2 remotes are supported.
However, you can do both the validation in one ajax call and return the custom error message in the response as in "username is already taken" or "email is already taken".

[Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) -
*The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; **or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message.***

Comment: The problem is that I'm using Zend and I'm doing a system that could validate errors on Server Side (via PHP) and on Client Side (via Jquery Validate, created on the fly by PHP classes that extends from the original Validators of Zend). 

In this context, I want to do a class that could generate more than one type of ajax validation in one field to support all possible cases that could happen on Ajax Validation for an input field...

Comment: I will put your answer as accepted because after some serious thought I think that you are right. If I did a system that allow the user to make more than one AJAX call for a field, it would be more overload to the server with requests and it could be done with just one url and different Parameters sent to it.